# Subbottom with no letters

Tags: numbering, subfloats

How can I remove the letters found before the captions made with `\subbottom`? The usual asterisk (like `\caption*`) doesn't seem to work.

```
\documentclass{memoir}% http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\newsubfloat{figure}% Allow subfloats in figure environment
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subbottom[Increase]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
  \subbottom[Increase]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
  \subbottom[Increase]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-c}}
  \caption{Round}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The standard `\subbottom` command (as can be seen using the code above) creates subcaptions starting with (a),(b),(c) under each figure. I would like to have the caption without the indexing (a,b,c,etc).

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3):

You can locally or globally redefine the subcaption setup. Here's the “local” version that will affect only one `figure` environment.

```
\documentclass{memoir}% http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir

\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx

\newsubfloat{figure}% Allow subfloats in figure environment

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{}% no subfigure number
\tightsubcaptions % we want tight subcaptions
\setlength{\subfloatlabelskip}{0pt}% no space between number and caption

\subbottom[Increase]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
\subbottom[Increase]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
\subbottom[Increase]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-c}}

\caption{Round}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For the “global” version, the three lines after `\centering` should go in the preamble.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution seems to be not to use the `subbottom`-command.

You could define a new command that typesets the minipage and the other stuff to save some typing.

```
\documentclass{memoir}% http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{showframe}
\newsubfloat{figure}% Allow subfloats in figure environment
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subbottom[Increase]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    }
    \subbottom[Increase]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    }
    \subbottom[Increase]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-c}
    }
    \caption{Round}
\end{figure}



Not using subbottom
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}\par
        Increase
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}\par
        Increase
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}\par
        Increase
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Round}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

If you *really* want to get rid of the numbers (letters) which are meant for referencing, add the following to the preamble.

```
\makeatletter
\@namedef{thesubfigure}{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: This looks ok. If it is not possible to remove the default numbering in subbottom captions, then I'll use this. It's weird, because, today I changed all my subfigures in subbottoms after reading that subcaption and memoir are not compatible. Now I'll have to do it all again because some default numbering...

Comment: You want to globally remove those numbers? Let me have a look at it.

Comment: I would like to globally remove those numbers. I looked in the memoir manual, and didn't find such an option.

Answer (score 1):

Another option, since in comments it has been mentioned that this is desired as a global setting, would be to patch `\@memsubcaption` to suppress the label:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newsubfloat{figure}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@memsubcaption}{\@nameuse{@@the#1}}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@memsubcaption}{\@nameuse{@the#1}}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subbottom[Increase]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
  \subbottom[Increase]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
  \subbottom[Increase]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-c}}
  \caption{Round}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does exactly what I wanted. Great job. I am curious how did you came up with this.

Comment: @BeniBogosel I read the code in `memoir.cls` to see how captions for subfloats were handled and detected the proper place to do the modification.